# how to convert 2012-05-03T25:00:00 to 2012-05-04T01:00:00 in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am not sure how this will be done in unix can anybody help/suggest to convert 
    `2012-05-03T25:00:00 to 2012-05-04T01:00:00` in Unix command/script

In my file I have more than one occurrence with different times those needs to converted to next day

```
2012-05-03T25:00:00 to 2012-05-04T01:00:00
2012-05-03T26:50:00 to 2012-05-04T02:50:00
2012-05-03T31:59:59 to 2012-05-04T07:59:59
```

etc

I tried it but somehow sed is not working

Date.txt

```
2009-09-12T05:18:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T05:24:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:24:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T05:25:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:25:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T05:27:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:27:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T30:29:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:29:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T29:31:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:31:@00@+10:00,D,
2009-09-12T28:33:00+10:00,,D,
2009-09-12T27:00:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T26:01:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:01:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T24:04:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:04:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T24:59:59+10:00,2009-09-12T05:06:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T30:08:00+10:00,2009-09-12T05:08:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T31:59:59+10:00,2009-09-12T05:10:@00@+10:00,U,
2009-09-12T05:17:00+10:00,,U,
2009-09-12T25:25:@00@+10:00,D,
```

script.sh

```
awk -F"T" -v OFS=',' '{print $1}' date.txt > tmpdate
uniq -d tmpdate > tmpuniq
rm tmpdate
date1=`cat tmpuniq`
date2=`date --set="$date1" +%F`
date3=$(date --date="$date2" -d "+1 day" +"%F")
T1=$date2+"T24"
T2=$date3+"T00"
echo $T1
echo $T2
dos2unix date.txt
#sed -i 's/$T1/$T2/g' date.txt > test.txt
#sed -i 's/"$T1"/"$T2"/g' date.txt > test.txt
sed -i 's/'$T1'/'$T2'/g' date.txt
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Hi Robert,its not an error that's the way our system generates the files

Comment: Why would the hour 25 be converted to the next day at hour 00? I would expect that 24 would be converted to 00 and 25 to 01.

Comment: Hi Greg, oops I did a mistake thanks I will update it

Comment: Do you have a time: `2012-05-35T987:224:1562`?

Comment: What are those @ signs doing in the data file?

Comment: I inserted intentionally. Later I need to replace with 50 i.e @00@ to 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Tcl on your system, the `clock` command makes it pretty easy:

```tcl
set t 2012-05-03T31:59:59
lassign [split $t T] date time
lassign [split $time :] hour min sec
set base [clock scan $date -format %Y-%m-%d]
set new [clock add $base $hour hours $min minutes $sec seconds]
puts [clock format $new -format %Y-%m-%dT%T]   ;# -> 2012-05-04T07:59:59
```

Update for cygwin:

first, using the cygwin installer, install the version 8.5.x of the "tcl" package (located in the Interpreters category). Then, you can do this

```
normalize_time() {
    printf '
        lassign [split "%s" T] date time
        lassign [split $time :] hour min sec
        set base [clock scan $date -format %%Y-%%m-%%d]
        set new [clock add $base $hour hours $min minutes $sec seconds]
        puts [clock format $new -format %%Y-%%m-%%dT%%T]
    ' "$1" | tclsh
}
normalize_time 2012-05-03T31:59:59
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I am using cygwin not sure how to use Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

You will basically need to parse the erroneous time specification, convert everything to seconds, add it back together, and convert it back to a proper date.

`date -d "date" +%s` produces seconds since January 1, 1970.  `date -d @1234567890` converts a date in this format back to a regular human-readable date.

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=T:

while read date hh mm ss; do
    basedate=$(date -d "$date" +%s)
    date -d @$(echo "$basedate+($hh*60*60)+($mm*60)+$ss" | bc) +%FT%T
done <<EOF
    2012-05-03T25:00:00
    2012-05-03T26:50:00
    2012-05-03T31:59:59
EOF
```

I didn't have `bc` on this computer so I replaced my original attempt with a small `awk` script, but it's not very readable.

```
awk 'END { print '"$basedate"'+('"$hh"'*60*60)+('"$mm"'*60)+'"$ss"'}' </dev/null
```

If you don't have a recent enough version of GNU `date`, you can find some alternative ways at http://www.antonolsen.com/2006/04/06/bash-convert-unix-timestamp-to-a-date/

Answer (score 0):

finally I got a solution with a bug (if date is last day of the month then this will not work but I can live with that)

and did a clumsy job

```
date1=`cat date.txt | awk -F. '{print substr($1,1,10)}'|uniq |head -1`
echo $date1
date2=$date1"T24"
date21=$date1"T25"
date22=$date1"T26"
date23=$date1"T27"
date24=$date1"T28"
date25=$date1"T29"
date26=$date1"T30"
date27=$date1"T31"
date3=$(date --date="$date1" -d "+1 day" +"%F")
echo $date2
cat date.txt | grep "$date2"
tmpdate=`echo $date1 | sed -e 's/-//g'`
echo $tmpdate
date4=`echo $(date -d $(echo \`expr $tmpdate + 1\`F) +"%F")`
echo $date4
date41=$date4"T00"
date42=$date4"T01"
date43=$date4"T02"
date44=$date4"T03"
date45=$date4"T04"
date46=$date4"T05"
date47=$date4"T06"
date48=$date4"T07"

sed -i 's/'$date2'/'$date41'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date21'/'$date42'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date22'/'$date43'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date23'/'$date44'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date24'/'$date45'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date25'/'$date46'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date26'/'$date47'/g' date.txt
sed -i 's/'$date27'/'$date48'/g' date.txt
```

If anyone wants to improve this script please go ahead.

Once again thanks to all.

Answer (score -3):

First, use cat 'yourfile' to open it. Then do a loop on each line. Then use grep and cut. That's really simple to do and the most efficient way for you to learn is to go through the man pages of cat, grep, and cut.
Hope it'll help.

Comment: None of these programs have any logic for calculating dates. They can remove uninteresting information, but not add interesting information. And the guidance to use `cat`is just plain useless.  http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: I thought he just wanted modify a file by hand. I didn't tink he wanted to calculate dates. But now you say that, it's true that there must be a logical way to calculate the dates, simply removing the hour and increment the date would be non-sens.

Comment: guys, I am still struggling.I posted my work any help much appreciated